# How can I get aggregated hourly visitors from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to find the best hours for scheduling maintenance on servers but it seems that Google Analytics is not able to show me the aggregated usage by hour for a period of time.

So far I was able to see visitors by hour but only for each day, I am looking for something that would aggregate or average this for an entire month or so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about analyzing data in Google Analytics.

Comment: @AlE. Interesting, what's the precedence for that? To me it seems in scope as it's asking how to use Google Analytics - a bona fide web application.

Comment: @andrewb: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3713/354

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom Report with the "Hour" dimension. It will aggregate by the hour.

eg:
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/permalink?uid=mz-C21ZJTaqOh-MxmaMhUw

Answer (score 0):

We have created a custom report for this purpose. Import this from the [Google Analytics Solutions Gallery](https://www.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.start%3D0%26_.tab%3DAll%26_.type%3D%26_.sort%3DDATE%26_.viewId%3D8VZs71cGQDO5m84ODYp1Yg/) (You need to be logged in with your Google Account to see this page).

This report also help you see the day of the week and date of the month analytics data.